# Loading MVT services and styles using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, style, vector-tiles, mapbox-vector-tile

I am using QGIS  Desktop 3.20.0 and want to use PyQGIS to load MVTservices to the layout and output the layout and end up with a PNG image.

I can never get the styles to load properly.

Using WMS services:

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/mapcache/vector_standard/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt](http://127.0.0.1:8000/mapcache/vector_standard/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.mvt)

Using the following way to load the layer loads successfully, but the style does not take effect.

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()


# method 1
uri = "styleUrl=file:///E:/data/service/vector%20tiles/mvt/style_test.json&type=xyz&url=http://127.0.0.1/mapcache/vector_standard/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.mvt&zmax=14&zmin=0"

rlayer = QgsVectorTileLayer(uri, "title")
project.addMapLayer(rlayer, addToLegend=True)

# method 2
uri = "type=xyz&url=http://127.0.0.1/mapcache/vector_standard/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.mvt&zmax=14&zmin=0"

rlayer = QgsVectorTileLayer(uri, "title")
load_msg, load_success = vector_tile_layer.loadNamedStyle(
    r"E:/data/service/vector_tiles/mvt/style_test.json", QgsMapLayer.AllStyleCategories
) # return ('', True) 
if load_success:
    project.addMapLayer(rlayer, addToLegend=True)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.loadNamedStyle is for QML styles or styles in the user database. It can not be used for loading the special JSON files that describe Vector Tile styles.

Comment: And I can confirm that setting the `styleUrl` also does nothing for me.

Comment: One can use `QgsMapBoxGlStyleConverter.convert(style_json_dict)` https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapBoxGlStyleConverter.html to get a `QgsVectorTileRenderer` and a `QgsVectorTileLabeling` but downloading the style JSON is not done automatically. To accept the bounty I would expect an answer to include the canonical way how QGIS itself handles the style JSON download.

Comment: It seems like `QgsMapBoxGlStyleConverter` is **not** all that QGIS uses if one loads a VT layer in the GUI. I have encountered missing streets and labels when using it as compared to a QML file exported from the QGIS GUI and loaded via `layer.loadNamedStyle()` :(

Answer (score 1):

This works but is not recommended, **you should never** use the `requests` library when working in PyQGIS (but QGIS' own network classes). I am posting this as MVP and as inspiration for others who might want to try to claim the bounty with a good answer.

```
layer = QgsVectorTileLayer(...)
import requests  # DONT DO THIS
style_url = "https://example.com/style.json"
style_json = requests.get(style_url).json()  # DONT DO THIS
converter = QgsMapBoxGlStyleConverter()
status = converter.convert(style_json)
assert status == QgsMapBoxGlStyleConverter.Success  # don't use assert in prod
assert not converter.errorMessage(), converter.errorMessage()  # don't use assert in prod
layer.setRenderer(converter.renderer().clone())
layer.setLabeling(converter.labeling().clone())
```

Best use `QgsNetworkAccessManager`'s methods instead of `requests` so that it works behind proxies etc.